# How do I fit a quasi-poisson model with lme4 or glmmTMB?

Tags: r, glm

I'm trying to fit a mixed-effects quasipoisson model in R. In particular I'm trying to replicate results obtainable in stata via the `ppml` command. `lme4` doesn't support the quasi-families. This link: https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#fitting-models-with-overdispersion has instructions for fitting quasibinomial models but not quasipoisson.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recipe given in the link will work just as well for (quasi)Poisson as for (quasi)binomial models. The key is that quasi-likelihood models really represent a *post-fitting adjustment to the standard errors of the parameters and the associated statistics*; they don't (or shouldn't ...) change anything about the way the model is fitted.

`glmer` is a bit fussy about "discrete responses" (binomial, Poisson, etc.) actually being discrete, but `glmmTMB` is looser/more forgiving.

This way of doing it puts as much of the variance as can be explained by the random effects there, then does a *post hoc* adjustment for any remaining over (or under)dispersion.

We'll use the [`grouseticks` data set from Elston et al 2001](https://rdrr.io/cran/lme4/man/grouseticks.html) (the original analysis used observation-level random effects rather than quasi-likelihood to handle overdispersion at the level of individual observations (= number of ticks counted on a single chick, nested within brood, nested within location).

```r
library(lme4)
g <- transform(grouseticks, sHEIGHT = drop(scale(HEIGHT)))
form <- TICKS~YEAR+sHEIGHT+(1|BROOD)+(1|LOCATION)
full_mod1  <- glmer(form, family="poisson", data=g)
```

There is moderate overdispersion: `deviance(full_mod1)/df.residual(full_mod1)` is 1.86. (Computing the ratio of (sum of squared Pearson residuals/residual df), as we will do below, is slightly more robust).

Unadjusted coefficient table:

```r
printCoefmat(coef(summary(full_mod1)), digits=2)
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)     0.47       0.19     2.4     0.02 *  
YEAR96          1.17       0.23     5.1    4e-07 ***
YEAR97         -0.98       0.25    -3.8    1e-04 ***
sHEIGHT        -0.85       0.12    -6.8    1e-11 ***
```

Now define the quasi-likelihood adjustment function (as in the link):

```r
quasi_table <- function(model,ctab=coef(summary(model))) {
    phi <- sum(residuals(model, type="pearson")^2)/df.residual(model)
    qctab <- within(as.data.frame(ctab),
    {   `Std. Error` <- `Std. Error`*sqrt(phi)
        `z value` <- Estimate/`Std. Error`
        `Pr(>|z|)` <- 2*pnorm(abs(`z value`), lower.tail=FALSE)
    })
    return(qctab)
}
```

Apply it:

```r
printCoefmat(quasi_table(full_mod1),digits=2)
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)     0.47       0.25     1.8    0.065 .  
YEAR96          1.17       0.30     3.8    1e-04 ***
YEAR97         -0.98       0.34    -2.9    0.004 ** 
sHEIGHT        -0.85       0.16    -5.2    3e-07 ***
```

As specified, the estimates are identical; the standard errors and p-values have been appropriately inflated, the z-values have been appropriately deflated.

If you prefer your statistics "tidy":

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(broom.mixed)
phi <- sum(residuals(full_mod1, type="pearson")^2)/df.residual(full_mod1)
(full_mod1 
  %>% tidy(effect="fixed")
  %>% transmute(term = term, estimate = estimate,
                std.error = std.error * sqrt(phi),
                statistic = estimate/std.error,
                p.value = 2*pnorm(abs(statistic), lower.tail=FALSE))
)
 term        estimate std.error statistic     p.value
  <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>
1 (Intercept)    0.467     0.253      1.84 0.0654     
2 YEAR96         1.17      0.303      3.84 0.000121   
3 YEAR97        -0.978     0.336     -2.91 0.00363    
4 sHEIGHT       -0.847     0.164     -5.15 0.000000260
```

- I don't know if any of the 'downstream' packages that people have built to handle mixed models (e.g. `merTools`, `sjstats`, etc.) have these capabilities. Arguably `broom.mixed` should/could build this in.
- all of the code above *should* work equally well with `glmmTMB()` substituted for `glmer`, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: But the `poisson` family expects integer data and the `quasipoisson` family accepts non-negative real numbers.

Comment: For some context as to *why* I'm trying to use the quasipoisson family on non-negative real numbers rather than count data, I'm trying to replicate the ppml see Silva, 2006 at https://watermark.silverchair.com/rest.88.4.641.pdf

Comment: when I go to that link I get "Token was not provided. Please go back to the article page and click the PDF link again."

Comment: How about this one: https://direct.mit.edu/rest/article/88/4/641/57668/The-Log-of-Gravity

Comment: (1) At least in TMB/glmmTMB, the Poisson distribution as implemented doesn't (I think) care if you give it non-integers [not sure about lme4::glmer ATM]; (2) warning that PPML and quasi-likelihood are not *necessarily* the same; (3) article is a little wishy-washy about use of GNLS ("shouldn't use GNLS because we want a nonparametric specification of variance; let's use QP which picks a particular parametric form")

Comment: Oh the article is wishy-washy all over the place. Coefficients do match up between glmmTMB and stata's ppml command, so thank you.  (The full mixed-effects model doesn't converge, but it doesn't converge in stata either.) Thanks again!